# Renaming Tags - Possible?

Tags: contacts

We've got about 100 tags we use to mark a contact's vertical market across thousands of contacts.

We've been asked to rename some of the tags for consistency, but I can't seem to find any way to do that.

We also tried creating a new tag set with the new tags, but as not all tags need to be renamed, I am not allowed to create  a duplicate tag, even if it is in a different tag set.

Is tags a Civi dead-end in this respect, or am I missing something?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have access to myphpadmin or do you know how to use the API Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to navigate to /civicrm/tag?reset=1 select a tag and click on the label on the right side (see screenshot). [image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: That does not work for me. When I click on the label of any tag, it remains stubbornly un-editable. I've checked everything I could think of that might cause this problem, but nothing fixes it. For example, this does not seem to be a permissions problem.

Comment: That's weird - maybe check your browser console if you have any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a search (with advanced search) for all contacts with tag to be changed,
then select all in the search and   and specify new tag

then select all again and   and specify the old tag.

Using this logic you may also decide you don't need the old tags deleted, you could simply not use them anymore.